# Laptop crashes when plugged in on AC and battery fully charged (Toshiba Satellite A300-1IW)

Tags: laptop, crash, battery, power

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite  [A300-1IW (model no PSAGCE-02000VFR)](http://www.toshiba.fr/discontinued-products/satellite-a300-1iw/). From several months it was crashed suddently when I used it on windows 7 or Xubuntu. Today I notice that the laptop is apparently crashed only when the laptop is plugged on AC power and the battery is fully charged.

I have read the event viewer and only a Kernel-Power error appears but with only few details (corresponding that the power has been shutdown).

On linux (Xubuntu) I noticed the same problems.

NB:

- the AC charger is working (I think) because it charges the battery.
- I can unplug the charger without problem.

So I am looking for someone who have a solution or an idea of the origin of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your kernal is damaged and it sends a turn-off signal after receiving a signal to stop charging? Try re-flashing it within kubuntu

Comment: I don't think so because I have the same problem with Windows 7. Anyway, I have fresh versions of xubuntu and windows 7 (I just install its).